# how to run CodeIgniter controller in cli while passing value with $_GET

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

How do i run a CodeIgniter controller in CLI (CentOS 6) while passing values through `$_GET` and/or `$this->input->get();`

I tried doing this:

```
php index.php <controller_name> [<method_name>] [<parameter_1> <parameter_2> ...]
```

and it works, but I need to pass $_GET values on the controller's method.

Comment: In another method that is calling method with GET parameters? `php index.php <controller_name> [<method2_name>]` and in `public function method2_name() { $this->method_name($parameter1, $parameter2) }`